# Equality at equilibrium of a ODE system arising in immunology

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling, biology

Consider the following system of ODE's [[1]](https://math.la.asu.edu/~kuang/paper/SMK15.pdf):
\begin{align}
\dot x & = \lambda - d_1 x - \frac{k_1 x v}{x + v}\\
\dot y & = \frac{k_1 x v}{x + v} - d_2 y - k_2 y \\
\dot s &= k_2 y - d_3s \\
\dot v &= as - d_4 v
\end{align}
where $x(t)$, $y(t)$, $s(t)$ and $v(t)$ represent the concentrations of
uninfected CD4+ T cells, infected CD4+ T cells in latent stage, productively infected CD4+ T cells and free virus (HIV), respectively. Under some condition, this system has unique strictly positive equilibrium $Q_2 = (x^*, y^*, s^*, v^*)$ that is locally asymptotically stable. Assume this condition. Then at $Q_2$, the system becomes:
\begin{align}
0 & = \lambda - d_1 x^* - \frac{k_1 x^* v^*}{x^* + v^*}\\
0 & = \frac{k_1 x^* v^*}{x^* + v^*} - d_2 y^* - k_2 y^* \\
0 &= k_2 y^* - d_3 s^* \\
0 &= a s^* - d_4 v^*
\end{align}

**My question is:** what justified the following equality? (cf. left side of p. 99 in [[1]](https://math.la.asu.edu/~kuang/paper/SMK15.pdf))
$$ k_1 = \frac{(d_2 + k_2) y^* (x^* + v^*)}{x^* v^*} \times \left[\frac{(d_2 + k_2) y^* (x + v^*)}{k_1 x v^*} \right] = \frac{x^* (x + v^*)}{x (x^* + v^*)}$$

Specifically, how are the following true?
$$ \left[\frac{(d_2 + k_2) y^* (x + v^*)}{k_1 x v^*} \right] = 1 $$
and 
$$ \frac{(d_2 + k_2) y^* (x^* + v^*)}{x^* v^*} \times \left[\frac{(d_2 + k_2) y^* (x + v^*)}{k_1 x v^*} \right] = \frac{x^* (x + v^*)}{x (x^* + v^*)}$$
I understand that the equation $ 0 = \frac{k_1 x^* v^*}{x^* + v^*} - d_2 y^* - k_2 y^* $ is the key, but I cannot figure out how the above two equalities are true.

---

[[1]](https://math.la.asu.edu/~kuang/paper/SMK15.pdf) Q. Sun, L. Min, Y. Kuang: "Global stability of infection-free state and endemic infection state of a modified human immunodeficiency virus infection model", *IET Syst. Biol.* **9**-3 (2015), 95–103 [doi:10.1049/iet-syb.2014.0046](https://dx.doi.org/10.1049/iet-syb.2014.0046)

Answer (score 1):

Solving

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
\lambda - d_1 x^* - (k_1 x^* v^*)/(x^* + v^*)  & = & 0\\ 
k_1 x^* v^*/(x^* + v^*) - d_2 y^* - k_2 y^*  & = & 0\\
k_2 y^* - d_3 s^* & = &  0\\ 
a s^* - d_4 v^* & = & 0
\end{array}
\right.
$$

for $k_1, d_1, d_3, d_4$  we obtain

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
k_1 & = & ((d_2 + k_2) (v^* + x^*) y^*)/(v^* x^*)\\
d_1 & = & (\lambda - (d_2 + k_2) y^*)/x^*\\
d_3 & = & (k_2 y^*)/s^*\\
d_4 & = & a s^*/v^*
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Substituting those values into

$(d_2 + k_2) y^* (x + v^*)/(k_1 x v^*)$ we obtain $((v^* + x) x^*)/(x (v^* + x^*))$

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't think this addresses my questions. The factor $\frac{(d_2 + k_2) y^* (x + v^*)}{k_1 x v^*}$ is quite mysterious to me.

Comment: As strange as it can be, it comes from the system resolution for the equilibrium conditions.

Comment: Could you please explain it further? How comes the term $x$ is in there and not $x^*$?

Comment: Sorry but I don't have access to the reference cited.

Comment: Please try this link: https://math.la.asu.edu/~kuang/paper/SMK15.pdf

Comment: It appears as if the author considers two $k_1$. The first as $k_1=\frac{(d_2k_2)(\bar y(\bar x+\bar \nu)}{\bar x\bar \nu}$ and another one as $k'_1 = \frac{(d_2k_2)(\bar y(x+\bar \nu)}{x\bar \nu}$ and then follows $k_1 =\frac{ k_1k'_1}{k_1} = \frac{\bar x(x+\bar \nu)}{x(\bar x+\bar\nu)}$. Really I don't know the reasons for that.

Comment: My point is that there is no reason why $k_1 = k'_1$.

Comment: You could also ask the authors at minlequan@sina.com